# Where to store program internal state?

Tags: server, bash

I need to write a program or a bash script, which will run every now and then (based on cron). The program will contain a state machine and will behave differently depending on which state it is in.

The program (or bash script) is not user specific, so it shouldn't be in the /home folder.

Where (by convention) to store the file with program internal state on Ubuntu Server?

Bonus question: What is the best place for the script itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best place for the script itself?

That could be ...

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

> Where (by convention) to store the file with program internal state on Ubuntu Server?

I do not think there is such a location. You could use `/var/local/`. I have seen several methods and a popular one seems to use `/opt/`. In this fashion:

```
/opt/{software_name}/ 
/opt/{software_name}{.version_1}/
/opt/{software_name}{.version_2}/
...
```

where the 1st is a symlink to the active version. And a `./bin` inside those directories for the binaries, a `./log` for a (rotated) log, and in your case a `./state` with or without a unique identifier. And all set to user root with permissions `n00` so nobody can read the content of "state".

Makes it clear where you can find anything you need.

Comment: Both /opt/ and a combo of /usr/local/ and /var/local/ would work equally well. Thanks. I just want to avoid any name collisions with present and future software coming from packages.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your script to be available for all users you should place it at `/usr/local/bin`, it's the best place for script and programs when you are installing them manually while other places are managed by package manger. If this script is only for moderators then it should be placed at `/usr/local/sbin`.

To save the state of your script you should consider that which user will run the script? will you run it using `root` in your `crontab` file? if that's the case so you should save the state at root's home directory in my opinion. you can also consider using `/tmp`

Comment: It should be executed only by cron (running as some specific user with specific privileges and should not be available to "human" users.

Comment: What about `/tmp` isn't it going work for you?

Comment: The state should be persistent across reboots. Nothing should modify the state other than the program itself.

Comment: so put it in `/var/lib/yourprogram`

Answer (score 3):

I'd make a folder for the data in `/var/local/` and store the script in `/usr/local/bin/`